# Flow footer being hidden for Utility Item bar

Tags: visual-workflow

I have one flow that is replacing the New button for a custom object.
Its using the entire screen. However on that app, we also have the Utility Item bar.
Since the flow screen has a lot of items, its footer ends up to be almost hidden, making it hard to be clicked and, of course, not pretty.

I've tried adding some sections on the screen but it wont solve, since the footer is always on the bottom of the flow.
The only "solution" that I current got is splitting the information in 2 (or more) different screens but yet its not a final solution because if one user is using a small screen, the problem will still come up.
Changing the Previous and Next buttons location would solve, but its not possible on the flow.

Any better suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is completely hide the footer and use custom buttons... You can use this UnofficialSF Flow Button Bar package to customize buttons, and then they will not be in the footer. Once you put them, you can add blank sections at the bottom in case it's still being covered.

https://unofficialsf.com/flow-button-bar-new-and-improved/

It looks like this more or less
[image]

Result:[image]